# Eliminating $x=-3,5$ when we solve the system $y=|3-x|, 4y-(x^2-9)=-24$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$y=|3-x|$$
$$4y-(x^2-9)=-24$$
I use two methods to solve it,

Method 1: Squaring both sides and eventually get a equation like this$$(x-5)(x-7)(x+3)(x+9)=0$$, $x=-9,-3,5,7$.

Method 2:Using $$y=3-x$$ and $$y=-(3-x)$$, and finally also get $x=-9,-3,5,7$

However, the answers are $x=-9,x=7$ only. 
Is there any method to eliminate $x=-3,x=5$ from the real answers? Or any other methods to avoid adding these 2 wrong solutions into the answers?

Comment: Substitute each of the answers into the original equation. Eliminate the ones that don't work.

Comment: (Alternatively: note that the equation $y=3-x$ holds only when $x\le3$, and similarly $y=-(3-x)$ only holds when $x\ge3$. So add that as a condition while solving your method 2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :
$$y=|3-x|$$
$$4y-(x^2-9)=-24$$
Make interval for this

For $x \gt 3$
$$y=-(3-x)$$
For $ x \le 3 $
$$y=(3-x)$$

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any method to eliminate $x=-3,x=5$ from the real answers?

For method 1 :

You have to have
$$x^2-33=4y=4|3-y|\ge 0\implies x^2\ge 33$$

For method 2 :

As f'' comments, note that $|3-x|=3-x$ holds only when $3-x\ge 0,$ i.e. $x\le 3$ and that $|3-x|=-(3-x)$ holds only when $3-x\lt 0$, i.e. $x\gt 3$.

So, if you have $y=3-x$, then you get
$$4(3-x)-(x^2-9)=-24\implies x=5,-9$$
with $x\le 3$. Therefore, $x=-9$ is the only solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You got extraneous solutions when you squared both sides of the first equation. To eliminate these, you can plug these back in, or you can note that you get extraneous solutions exactly when $y$ is negative, so you need to eliminate those solutions and keep those where $y$ is positive.